# Перебор элементов поля сводной таблицы, подключённой через olap

Tags: vba, olap

```
Dim a%, agr As PivotTable ', cbf As CubeFieldsD  '
Set agr = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
For a = 1 To agr.CubeFields.Count
    agr.CubeFields(a).Orientation = xlHidden
    agr.CubeFields(a).ClearManualFilter
Next
a = 0
With agr.CubeFields("[GSK_01_ColdFlu_breaks].[Competitor - main]")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With
agr.CubeFields("[GSK_01_ColdFlu_breaks].[Competitor - main]").EnableMultiplePageItems = True
agr.PivotFields("[GSK_01_ColdFlu_breaks].[Competitor - main].[Competitor - main]").VisibleItemsList = Array("[GSK_01_ColdFlu_breaks].[Competitor - main].&[Main]")
With agr.CubeFields("[GSK_01_ColdFlu_breaks].[Day]")
    .Orientation = xlPageField 
    .Position = 2
End With
agr.CubeFields("[GSK_01_ColdFlu_breaks].[Day]").EnableMultiplePageItems = True
With agr.PivotFields("[GSK_01_ColdFlu_breaks].[Competitor - main].[Competitor - main]")
    For Each b In .VisibleItemsList
        [e1] = b
    Next
End With
```

Как вернуть элементы  поля Competitor - main ?

Comment: а можно в более читабельный вид вопрос привести?